# Merging of rows based on data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In my application I am using SQL Server.  The output of one of the queries is:

```
Name            countA    countB   countC   countD   countE    countF
Name1           NULL       NULL       1       NULL  NULL        NULL
Name2           NULL       NULL       1       NULL  NULL        NULL
Name2           NULL       NULL     NULL      NULL  NULL        1   
Name3           NULL       NULL     NULL      NULL  NULL        1
Name3           NULL       NULL     6         NULL  NULL        NULL
```

I am expecting the output to be a single row representing the count data as is shown below.

```
Name            countA     countB    countC  countD  countE     countF
Name1           NULL       NULL       1      NULL    NULL        NULL
Name2           NULL       NULL       1      NULL    NULL        1  
Name3           NULL       NULL       6      NULL    NULL        1
```

What do I need to change to fix this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data, you should just be able to apply a `GROUP BY` to the query based on *Name*, and apply a `SUM` aggregate to *countA*, *countB*, etc.

Comment: Thank you :) got required output